# How to set Branch policy execution order

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, branch, pull-request

My scenario is bit complicated but I hope I get some input from here!!!

I am using Azure DevOps pipeline and Git repository.
Scenario is : I need to set up a branch policy to a branch in such a way that

1. There should be a reviewer
2. A work item should be attached
3. A gated pipeline build has to run before committing the code to the branch
   (Note Imp: as part of the gated build we have creating a delta file for database upgrade. and this delta file will commit as part
   of the gate)

Now the issue : I have configured the policy in git master branch as mentioned above. And I have created a pull request to master. As expected the gated build started execution and it created a delta file and committed the file to master before completing the pull request. if some one reject the pull request then the delta file created will remain orphan.

Is there any way I could wait the gated build to start only after the review completed?
or any API available to check the status of the branch policy in the pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

I've faced with such an issue and as a workaround, I've used the Az CLI Azure DevOps extension and "az repos pr policy list, az repos pr policy queue" commands
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/repos/pr/policy?view=azure-cli-latest#ext_azure_devops_az_repos_pr_policy_queue

Here is my PowerShell script to Trigger Manual build for PR validation

```
az extension add --name "azure-devops" --yes
az login 
$Data = (az repos pr policy list --id $(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId) --org <YourorgUrl> | ConvertFrom-Json)
$EvaluationId = ($Data | Where-Object {$_.context.buildDefinitionName -eq 'example'}).evaluationId
az repos pr policy queue --evaluation-id $EvaluationId --id $(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)
```

Add this step after dependent pipeline with automatic PR trigger

Comment: THANK you. this is the only thing I've seen which tells you where to find the evaluation id.  It took coming here and doing a final sanity check before creating a question on where to find the evaluation id to get this.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way I could wait the gated build to start only after the review completed?

I am afraid there is no such way to control the build to start only after the review completed.

In Pull Request, the **Build validation(Automatic)** will execute when the Pull Request Creating.

We currently have no way to control this branch policy to run after other branch policies are executed.

Here are two workarounds:

1. You could set the **Build validation** as **Manual**.

[image]

In this case, it can avoid automatically executing build when creating a pull request.

But as long as you have permission, you can manually queue this build.

2.You could [add Environment to your build Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops#approvals)(YAML).

In Environment, you could set up additional approved users.

[image]

In this case, the build will not be executed directly, it needs additional consent to run.

On the other hand, this requirement is valuable.

You could add your request for this feature on [our UserVoice site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21), which is our main forum for product suggestions.

Comment: Thank you Kevin. I have posted the request in product suggestions.